# IObservable swallows exceptions by default?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have an IObservable set up, and I'm trying to trigger it to transition from "cold" to "hot".  However, by pure dumb luck, I found that somewhere in the IObservable, an unhandled exception is throw.

I immediately freaked out because Reactive Extensions didn't let me know about this unhandled exception. 
 I guess the stream just terminated, instead.  Now I'm worried that Rx Extensions is going to be swallowing other exceptions.

This is the code I'm currently using to trigger the IObservable to be "hot".  I would expect that any unhandled exceptions that occur inside the IObservable to bubble up and be thrown here. But they are not.

```
var observable = Observable.Create<>(async a =>
  { 
    ... 
    a.OnNext();
    ...
    a.OnCompleted();
  });

observable = observable.Do(onNext: ..., 
  onCompleted: async () =>
  {
    // This throws the unhandled exception
    await MethodThatThrowsExceptionAsync();
  });


// I would expect any exceptions inside the IObservable to bubble up and be rethrown here.
await observable.LastOrDefaultAsync();
```

Am I doing something wrong?  Is this expected behavior?  This seems extremely error-prone if it is.

Comment: That's `OnError` is for.

Comment: Rx isn't swallowing exceptions; the `async void` lambda you're passing to `onCompleted` is what is causing the unhandled exception. You can't mix `async` with `Do`; you'll have to restructure your queries.

Comment: @PauloMorgado If I add an onError handler, it never gets hit.

Comment: @StephenCleary Are there any ways to pass an async to an oncompleted?  I also tried Subscribe, with the same result.

Comment: @StephenCleary - No luck. If I replace the async with something like MethodThatThrowsExceptionAsync().Wait() then the pipeline still just silently fails and ends prematurely

Comment: I would expect the `Wait` approach to work. Can you post a minimal repro?

I lived in Gaylord when I first got married! In TC now.

Comment: Where were you expecting to catch the exception?

Comment: @PauloMorgado The pipeline just silently stops mid stream, unless I have a debugger attached.  When an exception occurs *anywhere* in my code, I want it to fail horribly, sound the alarms, cry that the end is nigh, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`Do` is for expressing side-effects on the notification, and not to actually modify the notifications themselves. Throwing errors in `Do` is generally not advised.

If we break this down, you want to run a task when the observable is completed, in which you may throw an exception, which bubbles down.

There's an operator which can shunt another observable once it's completed - `Concat`.

```
    var observable = Observable.Create<int>(async a =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        a.OnNext(0);
        a.OnCompleted();
    });

    observable = observable.Concat(Observable.FromAsync(async () =>
      {
          await Task.Delay(1000); //simulate work

          // This throws the unhandled exception
          throw new Exception("I'm from async");              

          return 1; //type inference
      }));


    // This now throws
    await observable.LastOrDefaultAsync();
```

P.S.

Be careful when using `async/await` in place of `Action<>`. 
They fail silently.

Async void methods [considered harmful](https://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/).

Comment: Is the `Observable.FromAsync` required?

Comment: We don't want the task to start until after the first observable completes.

Comment: @JoshMouch what did you conclude

Comment: I ended up wrapping everything inside of an Observable into a try catch blocks, keeping track of them and rethrowing them as an AggregateException. Not great, but I'm sure nothing's getting lost now.